# Cut Sound of an Embedded Video

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, audio

I load a swf who contains flv video. I try to modify volume of sound but I don't know how do it...

Is there an netStream with soundtransform ?
Any volume property ?

Any idea ?

Regards,
Mathieu B.

Answer (score 0):

The `NetStream` class does have a [soundTransform](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html#soundTransform) property and the `SoundTransform` class does have a [volume](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/SoundTransform.html#volume) property.